# How to execute simultaneous builds in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

`build 1` is started to execute, I want to execute `build 2` even if the `build 1` is not fully executed (during the execution of `build 1` only).

But `build 1` should start first, because first build is server we need to start first, it won't stop during this execution only we need to start next build to obtain the proper output.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the number of executors is set to only 1 for your Jenkins.

Increase the numbers of executors for your Jenkins.

Go to **`Manage Jenkins > Configure System > # of executors`** (if job is running on master)

If the job is running on a specific node: **`Manage Jenkins > Manage Nodes > Your_node_name > Configure > # of executors`**

In your case you want to run two jobs at once so choose **`2`** executors.

Comment: it executing only one job it is not executing another one ,1st job blocking the 2nd job.

Comment: @SANTHOSHM.S even after increasing the number of executors?